# After FB logout programmatic transitions dont work (Swift)

Tags: facebook, swift, segue

having logged out with FB (keep in mind I havent yet updated to SDK 4.0 so that may be part of the issue), i try to switch views to another viewcontroller programmatically, but it doesnt work. Segues set up using the storyboard work fine, but this code no longer has any effect -

```
let logPage =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TheStart") as!  InitialLoginViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(logPage, animated:  false)
```

Why would this be?

Comment: This question will need more code. Why are you depending on FB Login? Is that related, or did you make other changes to your storyboard and viewcontrollers?

Comment: Sure! FB login is integral to the overall function (need's the user's friendslist). So I've done the usual place a UIView on the 'options' page. Changed it's class to FBLoginView and linked it up to the view controller (FBLoginDelegate). I'm using the code here to handle the login https://gist.github.com/iaserrat/4765b0f3532dfe87986e. The problem arises when loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser() is called. As soon as that happens, I'd like to transition to a separate 'login' page, but it doesnt work, as the code above doesn't programmatically change view anymore.

Comment: In the storyboard itself I have a navigation controller linked up to one view controller (the main page of the app), which till now has worked for transitions. E.g when the user logs in,                                                        func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView: FBLoginView) {
        let MapPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MapPage") as! MapController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MapPage, animated: false)
  
      
    }